# Using complex analysis to convert $b\cos \theta +a \sin \theta$ to a single trigonometric function

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, exponential-function

Using product $(a+bi)(\cos \theta+i \sin \theta) $ show that
$$b\cos \theta +a \sin \theta=\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}\sin(\theta+\arctan(b/a))$$
 and using this result show by induction that
$$ \frac{\operatorname{d}^n}{\operatorname{d}^nt}(e^{at}\sin (bt))=(a^2 +b^2)^{\frac{n}{2}}e^{at} \sin(bt+n \arctan(b/a))$$
Any hints on how to tackle this are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
r(\cos\theta + i \sin \theta) = r\mathrm{e}^{i\theta}
$$
and we can write any complex number in expoential form with the correct $(r,\theta)$
$$
a+ib = r\mathrm{e}^{i\phi} = r(\cos \phi + i \sin \phi)
$$

so 
$$
r\cos\phi = a,\\
r \sin \phi = b
$$
or 
$$
\tan \phi = \dfrac{b}{a}\implies \phi = \arctan \left(\dfrac{b}{a}\right)
$$

now
$$
r^2\cos^2\phi + r^2\sin^2\phi = a^2+b^2 = r^2\implies r = \sqrt{a^2+b^2}
$$

so we can write 
$$
a + ib = \sqrt{a^2+b^2}\mathrm{e}^{i\arctan \left(\dfrac{b}{a}\right)} = 
$$

the second brackets is readily in the form to make use of euler as
$$
\mathrm{e}^{i\theta}
$$
so we end up at
$$
(a+ib)(\cos \theta + i \sin \theta) = \sqrt{a^2+b^2}\mathrm{e}^{i\tan^{-1}\left(b/a\right)}\mathrm{e}^{i\theta}
$$
or
$$
\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\mathrm{e}^{i\left(\tan^{-1}\left(b/a\right) + \theta\right)}\tag{*}
$$

expanding the original product we get
$$
a\cos \theta -b\sin \theta + ib\cos \theta + ia\sin\theta 
$$
where the imaginary component is
$$
b\cos \theta + a \sin\theta 
$$
so now we know to obtain the the indenity we have to take the imaginary component of Eq.(*)
which is
$$
\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\sin\left(\tan^{-1}\left(b/a\right) + \theta\right)
$$

Comment: Do you any hints on how to do the induction proof?