# Variance of amplitude and phase from sin and cos regressors in polar coordinates

Tags: complex-numbers, signal-processing

On a data set, I estimated the sine and cosine weights at a specific frequency, $\beta_{\sin}$ and $\beta_{\cos}$. I can extract the amplitude and phase from these regressors as follows:

$$\textrm{Amplitude} = \sqrt{\beta_{\sin}^2 + \beta_{\cos}^2}$$

$$\textrm{Phase} = \arctan\left(\frac{\beta_{\sin}}{\beta_{\cos}}\right)$$

Associated with $\beta_{\sin}$ and  $\beta_{\cos}$ are variances of the parameter estimates. How do I properly convert these to polar coordinates?

Thanks

Comment: Not an exact answer, but may help you further what you have gotten so far :)..[trigonometric function to complex amplitude and phase](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/929981/using-complex-analysis-to-convert-b-cos-theta-a-sin-theta-to-a-single-trig/930080#930080)

Comment: This is a somewhat subtler question than I suspect most mathematicians realize.  I'm guessing your data include some values $x_i$, $i=1,\ldots,n$ whose sine and cosine are both to be evaluated for every $i$ without exception.  If the vectors $(\sin (fx_1),\ldots,\sin (fx_n))$ and $(\cos (fx_1),\ldots,\cos (fx_n))$ are not orthogonal to each other, then the least-squares estimates of the coefficients are correlated.  If you know they're not, then one could answer the question somewhat more simply.  If they are correlated, if I'm not mistaken, the problem is still perfectly tractable.

Comment: You suggest you know the variances of the parameter estimates.  Is their covariance similarly reported?

Comment: I think whoever voted to close this as unclear was mistaken.

Comment: I only have this for one frequency, and the $sin$ and $cos$ regressors are orthogonal. The least-squares estimates of the coefficients should be uncorrelated. You mention that that this makes the answer easier - how? Thanks.

Comment: If they are orthogonal, then the covariances mentioned in my answers are zero.  I'll add something to my answer about that.

Comment: I've added a postscript to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\var}{\operatorname{var}}\newcommand{\cov}{\operatorname{cov}}$For large sample sizes ("How large is 'large'?" is a question that could bear examination), the function $(\beta_{\cos},\beta_{\sin})\mapsto\arctan(\beta_{\sin}/\beta_{\cos})$ can be treated as locally linear.  Letting $\hat\beta$ be the least-squares estimate of $\beta$, we have
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial\beta_{\sin}} \arctan\frac{\beta_{\sin}}{\beta_{\cos}} = \frac{\beta_{\cos}}{\beta_{\cos}^2+\beta_{\sin}^2} \quad\text{ and }\quad \frac{\partial}{\partial\beta_{\cos}} \arctan\frac{\beta_{\sin}}{\beta_{\cos}} = \frac{-\beta_{\sin}}{\beta_{\cos}^2+\beta_{\sin}^2}.
$$
So we have a product of matrices, $(1\times2)(2\times2)(2\times 1)=\text{a scalar}$: 
\begin{align}
& \var \arctan\frac{\hat\beta_{\sin}}{\hat\beta_{\cos}} \\[12pt]
\approx {} & \left(\frac{(\beta_{\cos},\beta_{\sin})}{\beta_{\cos}^2+\beta_{\sin}^2}\right) \begin{pmatrix} \var\hat\beta_{\sin} & \cov(\hat\beta_{\sin},\hat\beta_{\cos}) \\
\cov(\hat\beta_{\cos},\hat\beta_{\sin}) & \var(\hat\beta_{\cos}) \end{pmatrix} \left(\frac{1}{\beta_{\cos}^2+\beta_{\sin}^2} \begin{pmatrix} \beta_{\cos} \\  \beta_{\sin} \end{pmatrix} \right).
\end{align}

A similar thing applies to the amplitude, but the derivatives are of course different.

**PS:** If $\displaystyle\sum_x \sin x\cos x=0$, where the sum is over all of the observed $x$-values in the data set, or in other words the sine and cosine are orthogonal, then the covariances are $0$, provided one has the usual assumptions about errors being uncorrelated and homoskedastic.  That makes the product of matrices equal to
$$
\frac{\beta_{\cos}^2\var\hat\beta_{\sin} + \beta_{\sin}^2\var\hat\beta_{\cos}}{\beta_{\cos}^2+\beta_{\sin}^2}.
$$

A similar thing can be done with the amplitude, but then of course the partial derivatives would be $(\partial/\partial\beta_{\cos})\sqrt{\beta^2_{\cos} + \beta^2_{\sin}}$ and $(\partial/\partial\beta_{\sin})\sqrt{\beta^2_{\cos} + \beta^2_{\sin}}$.